# c# Получить MessageID отправленного через VkApi сообщения

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api

Встал вопрос: работаю через VkApi с ботом вк в своей группе, пишу на c# (консольное приложение), в определённый момент идёт отправка сообщения (api.Messages.Send(...)), мне нужно получить его id что бы позже редактировать (api.Messages.Edit(...)), не могу найти способ получить id этого отправленного сообщения, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод Messages.Send  -  https://vknet.github.io/vk/messages/send/
возвращает ID сообщения.

Comment: благодарю, почему то не заметил этого, когда гуглил